# Cloning user meta from a Worpdress website to a destination website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to clone users from a WordPress website to another one on the same server keeping privileges and roles.

Table creation and data clone are ok for `wp_users` and `wp_userdata` but when I log in with my account I'm not an administrator on the destination website anymore. Worked on `wp_usermeta` and discovered that primary key and index had to be set manually so I did but no way to access as administrator.

This is what I used (in a PHP script)

```
CREATE TABLE wp_userdata SELECT * FROM wp_userdata_orig

ALTER TABLE wp_userdata ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID)

ALTER TABLE wp_userdata ADD ADD INDEX(meta_key)

ALTER TABLE wp_userdata ADD ADD INDEX(user_id)
```

But I'm still not recognized as administrator in the destination website.

I expect, after the cloning of the tables to log in in the destination website with the role I had in the origin website.

Answer (score 0):

The tables are called:

```
wp_users
```

and

```
wp_usermeta
```

The user_id in wp_usermeta have to match the ID in the table wp_users

Regards Tom

Comment: Ok, but wp_userdata is the wrong name for this table.It should be wp_usermeta.Just copy (export) the  two tables (wp_users & wp_usermeta) to the new database.

Comment: sorry .. the name is correct is wp_usermeta ... the name in the procedure is correct. it is wrong in my description here

Comment: ah, ok. Do you have access to phpMyAdmin? Then export the two tables from the old database and import them in the new database. If there are no relevant users in the new database you can truncate these two tables first.

Comment: hi ... thnx for replies... i can do it via phpmyadmin. no problem for this, but i need to install a kind of wp theme with a lot of custizations and i need make tjis process automatic... from the backend portal i handle users and they are synchronized during installation in the child portal. this is why i don't use phpmyadmin

Comment: Then do it once in the phpMyAdmin in copy the SQL statements out of the console. The problem is: you don't create the tables in a proper way. You don't need to create the new tables anyway when you export the wp_users and import it in the new database. Best would be if you delete the users and meta tables first on the new page and then import the SQL.